# Why is this linked-list initialization not working?

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to initialize (or create) a linked-list with an empty node pointing to `NULL`, but it's returning an error and I don't know why. Can somebody help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    int times;
    char name[100];
    char number[100];  
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node* node;

void mklist(node* n) {
    (*n)->times = 0;
    strcpy((*n)->name, "null");
    strcpy((*n)->number, "null");
    (*n)->next = (node)NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    node n;
    mklist(&n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't hide pointers behind a typedef...very confusing and error-prone.

Comment: I find it easier to work like that xD

Comment: [is it a good idea to typedef pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Answer (score 1):

So `node` is actually a pointer to a `struct node`, very confusing

```
typedef struct node* node;
```

In `main()` you declare a pointer and pass a pointer to a pointer to `mklist()`

```
node n;
mklist(&n);
```

In `mklist()`, `n` is actually a pointer to a pointer to the struct, so derefencing it, you get a pointer to a struct

```
void mklist(node* n){
    (*n)->times=0;
```

but nowhere in your code have you allocated memory for an actual struct.

The most straightforward fix with the way your code is currently is to add a `malloc()`

```
void mklist(node* n) {
    *n = malloc(sizeof(*(*n)));
    // check for malloc() failure

    (*n)->times = 0;
    strcpy((*n)->name, "null");
    strcpy((*n)->number, "null");
    (*n)->next = (node)NULL;
}
```

Comment: I have a lot of trouble with dynamic allocation, and I still don't understand it pretty well. Should I allocate the struct in the mklist() function?

Comment: You should allocate memory whenever you are adding and filling in a new node in your list.  Think of `malloc()` as actually building the struct for you to store information in.  `malloc()` within a function is perfectly fine, the memory is yours until you explicitly free it.  As long as you return a pointer to the new memory or correctly update existing pointers to point to it, you will maintain access to the memory.

Comment: Memory allocation is a tricky subject to grasp at first, so stick with it.  Eventually, data structures like linked lists will become second-nature if you keep playing with them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem. I will study more about pointers and allocation so it won't be a nightmare anymore haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in the global scope:

```
// nil = &nilObj, which means nil->next == nil.
// 
// This way, there's no checking for both 'nil' and 'NULL'!
// 
// As a consequence of this last point, you can make passing 'NULL'
// to most list functions invalid: it just means the user didn't
// use mklist() on every list they needed to manually work with.
static struct node nilObj = { 0, "null", "null", &nilObj };
node nil = &nilObj;

void mklist(node *n)
{
    *n = nil;
}
```

As Stephen Docy mentioned, using `typedef T *Tname;` is generally a bad idea as it hides the fact that you're using a pointer, which can be confusing when you use `Tname *n` as `(*n)->foo` (I'd expect to use it as `n->foo` honestly).  Some APIs do this, but they do it in a way that expresses that the variable is a pointer to an object rather than an object: instead of `Node`, something like `NodeRef` or `NodePtr` is used, signifying in the name that it's a pointer to a node, not a node.  Apple's Core Foundation API uses names like this (e.g. [`CFStringRef`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfstring-rfh)).  I highly suggest adopting a convention similar to this henceforth.  The above code I posted might then look something like this:

```
static struct node nilObj = { 0, "null", "null", &nilObj };
nodeRef nil = &nilObj;

void mklist(nodeRef *n)
{
    *n = nil;
}
```